# Not able to run robotframework using batch script on Pycharm

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, pycharm, robotframework

I have a batch script RunTests.bat

```
set CLASSPATH=^
jars/Automaton-1.3.2-all-deps.jar;^
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\abcd\app\abcd-jfx.jar;^
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\abcd\app\abcde-jfx.jar;^
C:\Users\desktopapp\Documents\automation\abcdKeywordLibrary.jar;.

jybot  %*
::jybot  --argumentfile %HOMEPATH%\robotArgFile.txt  C:\Users\desktopapp\Documents
:: --listener C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:53706:False
:: java -jar %HOMEPATH%\\AppData\Local\abcd\app\abcd-jfx.jar  com.abcd.application.launch
```

where abcdkeywordlibrary.jar is the jar library created for desktop application.

I am able to run this batch script on RIDE by just importing the location of the RunTests.bat under run command. I need to run this script on Pycharm for some purpose but when I run the same way by typing the command on terminal of Pycharm:

```
RunTests.bat -Tests test.robot
```

where 'Tests' is the folder under which the test.robot has the test case, variables and keywords. Then the Pycharm throws an error

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'test.robot' failed: Data source does not exist.
```

Not able to identify the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to the directory where tests are, or using full path when processing arguments.

```
CD C:\Users\desktopapp\Documents
jybot  %*
```